# Get current servlet request in Vaadin 7.6?

Tags: servlets, vaadin

Vaadin dev [ticket # 9505](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9505) says that `getCurrent…` methods have been added for getting the current VaadinServlet, VaadinPortlet, and so on.

Yet I do not see any such methods in the class doc. For example, these two pages:

- https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServletRequest.html
- https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinRequest.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are in:

- `VaadinServlet`: [getCurrent()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServlet.html#getCurrent())
- `VaadinPortlet`: [getCurrent()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinPortlet.html#getCurrent())
- `VaadinService`: [getCurrent()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinService.html#getCurrent()), [getCurrentRequest()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinService.html#getCurrentRequest()), [getCurrentResponse()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinService.html#getCurrentResponse())

  - `VaadinServletService`: [getCurrentServletRequest()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServletService.html#getCurrentServletRequest()), [getCurrentResponse()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServletService.html#getCurrentResponse())
  - `VaadinPortletService`: [getCurrentPortletRequest()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinPortletService.html#getCurrentPortletRequest()), [getCurrentRequest()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinPortletService.html#getCurrentRequest()), [getCurrentResponse()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinPortletService.html#getCurrentResponse())